# Explain a how the program put string in array

Tags: c#

I have this array

```
string[][][] levels = new string[15][][];
```

And in this arrayand I am putting multiple Questions/Answers separated by |

example :

> Whats the capital of Brasil?|Rio de Janeiro|Brasilia|Parana|Goiaba

To put to array i am using the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
levels[i] = File.ReadLines(@"l" + (i + 1) + ".txt).Select(s => s.Split('|')).ToArray();
}
```

The program splits and puts the question=x and answers=y on levels[15][x][y]

My question is: Can someone explain me this part of the code, and why it puts the question on x and answers on y?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. There are presumably 15 files, with each file containing a number of lines, with each line containing a question followed by a number of answers. Thus, `levels[i][j][k]` corresponds to file `i`, line `j`, question/answer `k`, where the question occurs when `k` is 0.

Comment: each file contains 3 lines similar to the example

Comment: Yes. `levels[i][j][0]` contains the question; `levels[i][j][1]` contains its first answer; `levels[i][j][2]` its second; and so on.

Comment: The .ToArray(); puts the string in the array? And when is the next question in the same txt file he puts it in levels[i][j+1][0] and so on right?

Comment: `s.Split('|')` creates the innermost `string[]` arrays (with each such array consisting of a question and its answers). The outer `ToArray()` takes the sequence of all `string[]` arrays for a file, and converts them into a `string[][]` array. Yes, `levels[i][j+1]` contains the question (and answers) following `levels[i][j]`.